# equalTo (jquery validate) not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

### Heading

I don't know why equalTo doesn't work.

I have reviewed several post but i cant find the answer.

This is the code!

I tried like 2 different ways but it still doesn't work. (ONLY PROBLEM WITH THE MATCH)

```
<?php
require_once("scr/register.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="register" method="post" action="scr/register.php">
                <label for="nickname">Nickname:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="nickname"><br/>

                <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="fullname"><br/>

                <label for="email">Email:</label><br/>
                    <input type="email" name="email"><br/>

                <label for="skype">Skype:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="skype"><br/>

                <label for="country">Country:</label><br/>
                    <select name="country">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option> 
                                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
                                <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
                                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
                                <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option> 
                                <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option> 
                                <option value="Angola">Angola</option> 
                                <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option> 
                                <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option> 
                                <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option> 
                                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option> 
                                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option> 
                                <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option> 
                                <option value="Australia">Australia</option> 
                                <option value="Austria">Austria</option> 
                                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option> 
                                <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option> 
                                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option> 
                                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option> 
                                <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option> 
                                <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option> 
                                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option> 
                                <option value="Belize">Belize</option> 
                                <option value="Benin">Benin</option> 
                                <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option> 
                                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option> 
                                <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option> 
                                <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option> 
                                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option> 
                                <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option> 
                                <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option> 
                                <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option> 
                                <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option> 
                                <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option> 
                                <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option> 
                                <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option> 
                                <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option> 
                                <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option> 
                                <option value="Canada">Canada</option> 
                                <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option> 
                                <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Chad">Chad</option> 
                                <option value="Chile">Chile</option> 
                                <option value="China">China</option> 
                                <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option> 
                                <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option> 
                                <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option> 
                                <option value="Congo">Congo</option> 
                                <option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option> 
                                <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option> 
                                <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option> 
                                <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option> 
                                <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option> 
                                <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option> 
                                <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option> 
                                <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option> 
                                <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option> 
                                <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option> 
                                <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option> 
                                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option> 
                                <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option> 
                                <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option> 
                                <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option> 
                                <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option> 
                                <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option> 
                                <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option> 
                                <option value="Finland">Finland</option> 
                                <option value="France">France</option> 
                                <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option> 
                                <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option> 
                                <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option> 
                                <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option> 
                                <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option> 
                                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option> 
                                <option value="Germany">Germany</option> 
                                <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option> 
                                <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option> 
                                <option value="Greece">Greece</option> 
                                <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option> 
                                <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option> 
                                <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option> 
                                <option value="Guam">Guam</option> 
                                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option> 
                                <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option> 
                                <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option> 
                                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option> 
                                <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option> 
                                <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option> 
                                <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option> 
                                <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option> 
                                <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option> 
                                <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option> 
                                <option value="India">India</option> 
                                <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option> 
                                <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option> 
                                <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option> 
                                <option value="Israel">Israel</option> 
                                <option value="Italy">Italy</option> 
                                <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option> 
                                <option value="Japan">Japan</option> 
                                <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option> 
                                <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option> 
                                <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option> 
                                <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option> 
                                <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option> 
                                <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option> 
                                <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option> 
                                <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option> 
                                <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option> 
                                <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option> 
                                <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option> 
                                <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option> 
                                <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option> 
                                <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option> 
                                <option value="Macao">Macao</option> 
                                <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option> 
                                <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option> 
                                <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option> 
                                <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option> 
                                <option value="Mali">Mali</option> 
                                <option value="Malta">Malta</option> 
                                <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option> 
                                <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option> 
                                <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option> 
                                <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option> 
                                <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option> 
                                <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option> 
                                <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option> 
                                <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option> 
                                <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option> 
                                <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option> 
                                <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option> 
                                <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option> 
                                <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option> 
                                <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option> 
                                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option> 
                                <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option> 
                                <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option> 
                                <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option> 
                                <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option> 
                                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option> 
                                <option value="Niger">Niger</option> 
                                <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option> 
                                <option value="Niue">Niue</option> 
                                <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option> 
                                <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Norway">Norway</option> 
                                <option value="Oman">Oman</option> 
                                <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option> 
                                <option value="Palau">Palau</option> 
                                <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option> 
                                <option value="Panama">Panama</option> 
                                <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option> 
                                <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option> 
                                <option value="Peru">Peru</option> 
                                <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option> 
                                <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option> 
                                <option value="Poland">Poland</option> 
                                <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option> 
                                <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option> 
                                <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option> 
                                <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option> 
                                <option value="Romania">Romania</option> 
                                <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option> 
                                <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option> 
                                <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option> 
                                <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option> 
                                <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option> 
                                <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option> 
                                <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option> 
                                <option value="Serbia and Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option> 
                                <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option> 
                                <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option> 
                                <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option> 
                                <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option> 
                                <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option> 
                                <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option> 
                                <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option> 
                                <option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Spain">Spain</option> 
                                <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option> 
                                <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option> 
                                <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option> 
                                <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option> 
                                <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option> 
                                <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option> 
                                <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option> 
                                <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China</option> 
                                <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option> 
                                <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option> 
                                <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option> 
                                <option value="Togo">Togo</option> 
                                <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option> 
                                <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option> 
                                <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option> 
                                <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option> 
                                <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option> 
                                <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option> 
                                <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option> 
                                <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option> 
                                <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option> 
                                <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option> 
                                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                                <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option> 
                                <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option> 
                                <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option> 
                                <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option> 
                                <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option> 
                                <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option> 
                                <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option> 
                                <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option> 
                                <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option> 
                                <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option> 
                                <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option> 
                                <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                                </select></br>
                <label for="address">Address:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="address"><br/>

                <label for="city">City:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="city"><br/>

                <label for="zip">Zip:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="zip"><br/>

                <label for="bankname">Bank Name:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="bankname"><br/>

                <label for="bankaccount">Bank account:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="bankaccount"><br/>

                <label for="beneficiary">Beneficiary:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="beneficiary"><br/>

                <label for="username">Username:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="username"><br/>

                <label for="password">Password:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="password"><br/>

                <label for="password2">Repeat Password:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="password2"><br/>

                <label for="when">When do you plan to start working?:</label><br/>
                        <select name="when">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select one</option> 
                            <option value="immediately">Immediately</option>
                            <option value="week">Week</option>
                            <option value="month">Month</option>
                        </select><br/>

                <input type="submit" value="Register" id="boton">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#register").validate({

            rules: {

                    nickname: "required",
                    fullname: "required",
                    email: {required:true, email:true},
                    skype: "required",
                    country: "required",
                    address: "required",
                    city: "required",
                    zip: {required:true, number:true},
                    bankname: "required",
                    bankaccount: "required",
                    beneficiary: "required",
                    username: "required",
                    password: "required",
                    password2: {required:true, equalTo: "#password"},
                    },

                messages: {

                    nickname: "Nickname is required",
                    fullname: "Full Name is required",
                    email: "Email is required and use a valid email",
                    skype: "Skype is required",
                    address: "Address is required",
                    city: "City is required",
                    zip: "Zip is required",
                    country: "Country is required",
                    bankname: "Bank Name is required",
                    bankaccount: "Bank Account is required",
                    beneficiary: "Beneficiary is required",
                    username: "Username is required",
                    password: "Password is required",
                    password2: "Re-Password is required and match with Password",
                }
        });     
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `id="password"` for your password input:

```
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" /><br/>
```

Also you need to close your input properly using `/>` because `input` is a self-closing tag just like `<br />` or `img />`. Currently, all of your inputs are not closing using `/>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified id selector in the `equalsTo` rule but there is no id for the password input element

```
<input type="text" name="password" id="password">
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8EzAL/)

Also note that, the type of password field should be password so that it will not use plain text display

Comment: Yes, i know about password field.